# Is there a way to pass Optional Int to JNI layer?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

(Java Code) AAuthenticationService.java

```
public AuthTokenProperties(String sessionId, Optional<Integer> ttl) {                            
        m_cppRef = CppCreate();
}
private native long CppCreate();
```

Jni Layer

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL
Java_AAuthenticationService_CppCreate(JNIEnv *env, jobject jniAuthenticationService)
{
}
```

I need to pass this sessionID and Optional Integer ttl to CppCreate() which is a native function, Is there any way to pass this Optional ??

Comment: Can you modify the native function (at the C/C++ side)?

Comment: Did you mean, passing Int from Java world instead of Optional<Integer> and modify my Native Function to use Integer instead of Optional<Int>...Nope I can't do this :(

Comment: No, I meant if you're the author of the native function, so you can change it to your needs. Basically, the signature will include a jstring for your sessionID and a jobject for the Optional, but I'll have to try,

Comment: If you can modify the JNI code that you posted, you can add any arguments you want. Keep in mind that calling methods of any object arguments requires a lot more work, with method lookups etc. I don't know if switching to JNA is an option, that allows you to better mix native and Java code.

Comment: @RobSpoor , I got your point, like I can add more arguments to my JNI Code...but Since I want to pass an Optional<Integer> from Java, In JNI Code, what would be the arguement signature for that??

Comment: You don’t want to pass neither an `OptionalInt` nor an `Optional<Integer>` to JNI. Ideally design two methods, one that takes an `int` argument and one that does not. Also `Optional` in Java is for return values from methods. I still haven’t seen an example where it has got any advantage as method argument.

Comment: @Mihe, If that works for you, can you please share dummy Implementation, would be great help :)

Comment: @TheBlank I generally let the JNI interface be generated, but I think that `OptionalInt` and `Optional<T>` for any `T` are just `jobject` in JNI. However, I agree with Ole, you don't want to too much Java-based logic in JNI. All the overhead usually isn't worth it.

Comment: I think the best way would be then to create 2 methods one with Int and one without. Thanks @RobSpoor !!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, assuming you have an `Optional<Integer>` passed to C++ as `jobject optInt`:

```
jclass cls_Optional = env->GetObjectclass(optInt);
jmethod mid_Optional_isPresent = env->GetMethodID(cls_Optional, "isPresent", "()Z");
if (env->CallBooleanMethod(optInt, mid_Optional_isPresent)) {
  jmethod mid_Optional_get = env->GetMethodID(cls_Optional, "get", "()Ljava/lang/Object;");
  jobject obj = env->CallObjectMethod(optInt, mid_Optional_get);
  // do something with obj, probably call `intValue()` or `longValue()`.
} else {
  // Optional was empty.
}
```